# Display many variables in same error message in String.Format

Tags: c#

I need to display error message with different variables,

I have a list :

```
  List<Tuple<int, string>> listrailcar = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
        listrailcar.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(21458, "overfilled"));
        listrailcar.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(9986, "overweighed"));
        listrailcar.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(9986, "overtotal"));
```

to dispaly my error message:

```
 foreach (var item in listrailcar)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("error processing :Railcar number : {0}" + " is " + "{1}", item.Item1, item.Item2));
        }
```

The result is three sentences :

[image]

but I want just one message with the three variables,like this:

"error processing :Railcar number : 21458 is overfilled .
                                    9986 is overweighed.
                                    2156 is overtotal. "

How can I fix it?

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly is your problem? Is it just that you don't know how to build a string in a loop? StringBuilder should be what you are looking at for best performance with unknown size of data but standard string concatenation should be fine for the sort of data you are looking at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Console.Write` instead, and write out the first part of the text, then loop through the items in the List.

```
Console.Write("error processing Railcar: ");
foreach (var item in listrailcar)
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0}" + " is " + "{1}. ", item.Item1, item.Item2));
}   
Console.WriteLine();
```

Output:  
`error processing Railcar: 21458 is overfilled. 9986 is overweighed. 9986 is overtotal.`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to se a StringBuilder and append the messages in your loop to it, writing it to the console at the end:

```
using (var errorMessages = new StringBuilder("error processing :")) {
    foreach (var item in listrailcar)
    {
        errorMessages.append(string.Format("Railcar number : {0}" + " is " + "{1}", item.Item1, item.Item2));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use a solution like this which is way more object oriented?

```
void Main()
{
    List<RailCar> railCars = new List<RailCar>();

    foreach(var railCar in railCars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error processing: RailCar number: {railCar.Number}. {railCar.OverFilled} is overfilled. {railCar.OverWeighed} is overweighed. {railCar.OverTotal} is over total.");
    }
}


public class RailCar
{
    public string Number { get; set;}

    public int OverFilled { get; set; }

    public int OverWeighed { get; set; }

    public int OverTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq Aggregation you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("error processing :Railcar number: " + listrailcar.Aggregate("", (current, tuple) => current + $" {tuple.Item1} is {tuple.Item2}."));
```